# How does an organizational user install an Office Add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I developed an add-in for Word.

The [Microsoft docs state that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/implement-licensing-for-add-in-services#step-2-create-a-licensing-database)

> To sell Office Add-ins to organizations, you need to create a licensing database. This is necessary because:
>
> - ...
> - Centralized deployment does not allow users to buy add-ins from AppSource and deploy them. AppSource paid add-ins today only work with personal identities (Microsoft accounts), ***not work or school accounts.***

So, if I want an organization to adopt my Office Add-in I have to handle the licensing workflow myself. And if I understand this correctly, an organizational user would not download/install my add-in thorough the AppSource(AS). So...

***How does an organizational user actually get the add-in?*** They don't purchase it from the AS—their organization already purchased the add-in. So how does the user "find" the add-in and install it in their Office instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an add-in uses Centralized Deployment, the add-in is automatically installed for all users. For example, if it has ribbon buttons, they will automatically appear on the ribbons of the users for whom the add-in has been deployed. So, the user doesn't do anything to install the add-in. For details about how this works, see [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment).